# Spring Batch jdbcbatchitemwriter afterpropertiesset repeat trigger twice

Tags: spring-batch, itemwriter

Why spring batch jdbcbatchitemwriter afterpropertiesset repeat trigger twice?

```
 @Autowired
 TestWriter write;

public Step startStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilders) {
        return stepBuilders.get("step")                
                .listener(new StepResultListener())
                .<Map, Map>chunk(chunkSize)
                .reader(....)
                .processor(....)
                .writer(write)
                .faultTolerant()
                .build();
    }
```

and TestWriter.java code is

```
@Bean(name = "write")
    @StepScope
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Map> write() {
        .....
        
        JdbcBatchItemWriter<Map> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
        itemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
        itemWriter.setSql("insert into student (id,name) values (?,?) ");        
        ItemPreparedStatementSetter setter = new ItemPreparedStatementSetter() {
            @Override
            public void setValues(Object o, PreparedStatement preparedStatement) throws SQLException {
                ......
            }
        };
        itemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(setter);
        itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
        return itemWriter;
    }
```

I debug in JdbcBatchItemWriter afterpropertiesSet(), I found this function will call twice.
Please tell me why?
I want `afterpropertiesSet()` this function only call one.

Answer (score 2):

The method `afterPropertiesSet` is not specific to Spring Batch but is part of the underlying Spring Framework. If a class has such a method and an object of that class is exposed as a bean, Spring will call the method after it has set all properties of the object.

You should remove your invocation of the method from the factory bean method for the `JdbcBatchItemWriter`. Then it will we invoked only once by Spring.

You should only invoke the method yourself in situations when objects of a class that are expected to be used as beans (or expected to have `afterPropertiesSet` called) are not actually managed by Spring.